# can we make an application to hang up the dialed call for x amount of second from our application iphone sdk

Tags: ios4

I want to develop an iPhone application whose main function is to hang up an outgoing phone call after X amount of seconds/minutes have passed since the call was placed, not from when the call was connected. After hanging up, the application will automatically redial to continue the phone call without any user intervention. The application will only redial in the case the same application has hanged up the call. If any of the parties hang up the call, the application will not redial.

Expected features to be developed are:

1. Add and update a list of phone numbers to monitor

The user must be able to type in directly a phone number or select it from the address book. The list will show the name and phone number monitored like “Roberto Ibarra: 33 5555 5555”. This list will serve as the database of phone numbers the application will identify as outgoing calls that must be hanged up and redialed automatically after X amount of minutes have passed. The application must not affect incoming calls or outgoing calls to numbers other than the ones on this list.

If possible, the application must fully integrate with the OS dialing system so that calls placed from any part of the phone will be monitored. For example, if a call is dialed with voice commands it should be monitored by this application.

2. Alert and hang up

The application must send a BEEP 5 seconds before hanging up, so as to both parties in the call can hear it and be aware the call will be about to end. This will not be configurable by the user, it will always happen 5 seconds before ending the monitored call. If the call is an outgoing call and the number is part of the list of numbers to monitor, the application will then hangup the call once the X amount of minutes/seconds have been reached. This beep can be a DTMF tone.

3. Automatically redial a monitored call that was ended by the application

The application will automatically redial the number that was being called to continue the call ONLY if the call was automatically ended by the application because the time limit was reached. If the call was ended by the user, then the call must NOT be redialed.

4. Copy protection mechanism

The application must have a copy protection mechanism based on the phone's IMEI. The application must ask the first time for a code and show the phone's IMEI. The code will be generated by a third party website by entering the IMEI and if correctly entered in the phone, then the application will work.

The algorithm will be based on a hash from the IMEI and some seed to be determined. The crypt function should be something like MD5 or some other function available in the OS in the majority of the phones using the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot do this**. You have no access to calls made from the device and certainly can't hangup any in process calls. The closest you can come is asking the phone application to dial a number.